# Reduce with extra arguments to the function in R

Tags: r, merge, functional-programming, reduce

I'm trying to use the `Reduce` function in R to use the `merge` function across multiple dataframes.  The problem is, I would like to use the merge function with the argument `all=T`, and there seems to be nowhere to specify this in the higher-order `Reduce` function.

So I'd like:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4), a=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
b <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 5, 6), b=c('a', 'b', 'e', 'f'))
c <- data.frame(id=c(3, 4, 5, 6), c=c('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))

out <- Reduce(merge, list(a, b, c), all=T)

out
  id    a    b   c
1  1    a    a <NA>
2  2    b    b <NA>
3  3    c <NA>   c
4  4    d <NA>   d
5  5 <NA>    e   e
6  6 <NA>    e   e
```

But because `merge` defaults to `all=F`, what I'm getting is:

```
[1] id a  b  c 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As far as I know, `Reduce` can not handle extra parameters to be passed to the function parameter yet. But you can redefine the `merge` function with customized parameters and pass it as an anonymous function to `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "id", all = T), list(a, b, c))

#  id    a    b    c
#1  1    a    a <NA>
#2  2    b    b <NA>
#3  3    c <NA>    c
#4  4    d <NA>    d
#5  5 <NA>    e    e
#6  6 <NA>    f    f
```