# Loop with left join gives me an error " UseMethod ("left_join") error: No Applicable method for 'left_join' applied to object of class "list""

Tags: r, loops, left-join

I try to create a loop that makes join to 5 dataframes like this

```
c <- list(EC_Pop, EC_GDP, EC_Inflation, ST_Tech_Exp, ST_Res_Jour)

for (i in seq_along(c))
{
  if (i < 2)
  {
    EC_New <- c[i] %>%
      left_join(c[i+1], by = c("Country","Year"))
  }
  else if(i > 1 & i < 4) 
  {
    EC_New <- EC_New %>%
      left_join(c[i+1], by = c("Country","Year"))
  }
  else
  {
    EC_New
  }
}
```

But I have an error :  `UseMethod ("left_join") error: No Applicable method for 'left_join' applied to object of class "list"`

Can somebody explain the reason? It seems very logical for me the way I wrote it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `left_join`, both `x` and `y` must be *data frames*.

Your `c` is a *list*, and so is `c[i]`.

However, `c[[i]]` is a data frame. So change your code to include two square brackets.

```
EC_New <- c[[i]] %>%
      left_join(c[[i+1]], by = c("Country","Year"))
```

---

I think you can also replace your code using `Reduce`:

```
EC_New2 <- Reduce(left_join, c)
```

Then check:

```
identical(EC_New, EC_New2) # should be TRUE
```

But I'm not sure since I don't have your data. It should work if the common columns are *only* "Country" and "Year".

And thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000509/reduce-with-extra-arguments-to-the-function-in-r) answer, you can use the following command if the "Country" and "Year" are **not** the only common columns.

```
EC_New2 <- Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by=c("Country","Year")), c)
```

---

By the way, try not to use function names such as `c` to name your R objects. While R allows this, it can lead to confusion later. For example, if you want to concatenate `x` and `y` but accidentally type `c[x, y]` instead of `c(x, y)`, R may not return an error but something totally unexpected.